# Y axis Zooming properly but X axis is not Zooming

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I am trying to make a graph in which Y Axis contains memory of an executable and X axis contains time.
I have made the following code

```
        minValue = DateTime.Now;
        maxValue = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);

        chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum = minValue.ToOADate();
        chartArea1.AxisX.Maximum = maxValue.ToOADate();

        chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chartArea1.CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chartArea1.CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
        chartArea1.CursorY.AutoScroll = true;
        chartArea1.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
        chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        chartArea1.AxisY.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1)


        Series newSeries = new Series("Series1");
        newSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
        chart1.Series.Add(newSeries);
```

Now when after adding points when i am trying to zoom the selection line comes only for y axis and not for the x axis.Hence i am unable to zoom the x axis.Can anyone help on what can be the problem

Answer (score 0):

It was not zooming due to the reason i was using XValueType as ChartValueType.Time.When Time is converted in double the integer part remains the same whereas only decimal part changes.Hence there was only one integer point on the X Axis an hence zooming was disabled

Comment: Did you find a way to overcome this?